# Sales Order grid new column order comment show recent comment only

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, order-grid

In magento CE 1.7.0.2

Add new column to sales order grid which have a most recent order comment.

Following code used to add column

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    // Add order comment to grid
    $this->addColumn('ordercomment', array(
        'header'       => Mage::helper('ordercomment')->__('Order Comment'),
        'index'        => 'ordercomment',
        'filter_index' => 'ordercomment_table.comment',
    ));

    // Fix integrity constraint violation in SELECT
    foreach ($this->_ambiguousColumns as $index) {
        if (isset($this->_columns[$index])) {
            $this->_columns[$index]->setFilterIndex('main_table.' . $index);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

But comment shown in grid is first comment on order.

How most recent comment will show in this column?

Comment: Im wanting to do the same but so that is shows which vat rate the order has used i.e. 5% or 0% or 20%
probably a drop down of the rates avaliable

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify a more specific data type on the `addColumn`:

- action
- checkbox
- concat
- country
- currency
- date
- datetime
- input
- interface
- ip
- longtext
- massaction
- number
- options
- price
- radio
- select
- store
- text
- theme
- wrapline

You will find all these types in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer`

You can also make your own grid renderers the same way.

- http://code007.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/grid-column-types-in-magento/

---

If you're making comments like these, question what you're doing is correct.

`//Fix integrity constraint violation in SELECT`